# JDK 13 Upgrade Issue

Tags: javafx, ejb-3.0

I had a JavaFx project running perfectly on JDK 8. To connect with the database, the client calls remote interface which in turn calls the EJBs deployed on the server.

However, after successfully upgrading the JDK to 13, I am getting the below error when the database call is made...

```
SEVERE: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446347 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: 00810011: Exception from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 11 completed: Maybe
javax.ejb.EJBException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446347 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: 00810011: Exception from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 11 completed: Maybe
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:127)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:99)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.loadView(Unknown Source)
```

Any hints on how to resolve this issue are highly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like WebLogic, it may not be supported on JDK 13 at this time.

Comment: You are correct, WebLogic doesn't support JDK 13 yet... However my EJB project still runs on JDK 8 and is deployed on WebLogic 12.2... I am just trying to get the client to run on JDK 13

Comment: @Sirish V I do not think you can use JDK 13 with JavaFX that said where this may be a driver issue What is the database

Comment: My application runs on Oracle 12c. Some of the database calls work fine though, may be its a driver issue related to serialization of certain objects... I'm still investigating.